# Vue 3: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: vuejs3

I want to show list product from api but it shows the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
at eval (Home.vue?bb51:103)
at renderList (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6635)
at Proxy.render (Home.vue?bb51:2)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:1166)
at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5265)......
```

my product like :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "chair",
    "categoryId": 12,
    "unitId": 2,
    "price": 66000000,
    "salePrice": 0,
    "material": "wood",
    "size": "x"
  },
]
```

My code here:

Home.vue file

```
 <ProductCard v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" :product="product" />
```

ProductCard.vue file

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "ProductCard",
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

ProductService.js file

```
const apiClient = axios.create({        
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8888/api/v1',
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})

export default {
    getProducts() { 
        return apiClient.get('/product/get-list-product-by-subcategory')     
    },
}
```

When I print out list product in console. It still work.

Does anyone know where is the bug in my code?

#### Updated:

I try to fix my bug "Cannot read property 'id' of null", Steve's answer although remove my red warning in devtool but not deal my data: my data still not showing up. And I find out my code work by using `this.products = response.data.data`

```
ProductService.getProducts()
      .then((response) => (this.products = response.data.data))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error: " + error));
```

Explain by myself is:
When `console.log(this.products = response)`
[image]

And I need to use this.products = response.data.data to enter to array

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apiClient.get(...)
```

returns a promise not the actual data from the API call.

You need to add a then. like so

```
apiClient.get(...).then(response => (this.products = response))
```

Then when the apiClient.get completes this.products will be populated with the data from the API.

Comment: Oh. Thanks bro. I see my bug. I use `apiClient.get(...).then(response => (this.products = response.data))`. It is wrong at response.data and I remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ProductCard v-for="product in products" :key="product._id" :product="product" />
```

Comment: Console show error: Cannot read property '_id' of null

Comment: Check you products object. Console it and check it contain id or _id.

Comment: it is 'id' like product format I mention to :((((